# D3 styling SVG elements when defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a D3 chart with an axis that I want to style via the original calls to create it. However it only seems to work on the first call. I'll show you what I mean:

When I create the axis via

```
svg.select('g.y.axis').call(yaxis)
    .selectAll("path")
        .attr("fill","none")
      .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .selectAll("line")
        .attr("fill","none")
      .attr("stroke", "#000");
```

Only the path is styled correctly. You can check out my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f07sekwj/4/) to see what I mean. I know this may be slower than just having CSS styles but I need it to be styled in the original call for what I'm working on. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `d3.selectAll("foo").selectAll("bar")` will try to find `<bar>`s that are inner elements to founded `<foo>`s. And in your case svg finds no `<line>`s in `<path>`s.

Just call separately:

```
svg.selectAll("path")...
svg.selectAll("line")...
```

*UPD*
To find path/line in .y.axis:

```
svg.select(".y.axis").selectAll("path")
```

or

```
svg.selectAll(".y.axis path")
```

Comment: However when I do that it will style all lines and paths with that style. I only want to style the ones in the axis.

Comment: Just set relative path. For example, to get `.tick`s that are in `.x.axis` I should call `d3.selectAll(".x.axis > .tick")`.
Seems in your case it should be `svg.selectAll(".y.axis path")` and `svg.selectAll("y.axis line")`. It's the same to  `svg.select(".y.axis").selectAll("path")` and `..."line"`.